# NoClassDefFoundError while running .jmx command line using lazerycode jmeter plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using [lazerycode jmeter maven plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/) to execute my jmeter tests.

When I try to run my jmx file from the UI, it runs perfectly fine.

but, when I try with to do with mvn,

```
mvn clean install or mvn verify
```

It starts executing but it fails at a point where I have used the JSON extractor to extract some values from response. Below is the error I get,

```
[INFO] Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonReader. See log file for details.
```

This is the POM that I am using:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <!-- Some user properties here -->
                    </propertiesUser>

                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:0.19</artifact>
                        <artifact>Kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs:1.3.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:jar:2.3</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <!-- The plugin uses some broken dependencies
                         An alternative is to set this to true and use excludedArtifacts, see below
                    -->
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Below is the complete logs from the jmeter log file:

> 2018-02-11 18:44:20,835 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished:
>   Thread Group 1-1 2018-02-11 18:44:20,857 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught
>   exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonReader   at
>   com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.process(JSONPathExtractor.java:102)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-extras-libs-1.3.1.jar:?]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:833)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core-3.3.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:524)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core-3.3.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core-3.3.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core-3.3.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151] Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_151]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_151]    ... 6 more

I have added multiple libraries in the pom.xml as described [here](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding%20Additional%20Libraries%20To%20The%20Classpath) but the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is recommended to use latest versions of [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version), its Maven plugin and JMeter Plugins so I would recommend amending your *pom.xml* like:

   ```
   <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.7.0</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                           <phase>verify</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>jmeter</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
                   <configuration>
                       <jmeterExtensions>
                           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:jar:2.6</artifact>
                           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:0.19</artifact>
                           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs:1.4.0</artifact>
                       </jmeterExtensions>
                       <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </project>
   ```
2. It might be an issue with Maven caches so I would suggest running it at least once with `-U` key like:

   ```
   mvn -U clean verify
   ```
3. If you still experience problems run your test with `-X` key to enable full debugging output and update your question with it (you might also need to provide your .jmx script)

More information:

- [Maven Command Line Options](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

**EDIT:**
Thanks Dmitri, this was really helpful. In my case I had to add additional library in the pom.xml to resolve this error.

```
<artifact>com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0</artifact>
```

I am editing this answer because more often, people don't look into comments to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your detailed answer. The problem in my case was that it was expecting another library to be downloaded. I added `<artifact>com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0</artifact>` line in my pom and it started working fine.

Comment: Before I accept your answer, I have one more question, If we are using lazerycode, how can we run a single test? `mvn verify` seems to run all the tests in the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

@Harish Talanki, you can give like this in your pom file if u want to run just one jmx file inside the configuration tag

```
<configuration>
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <jMeterTestFile>samplefile.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
```